# Sending PUT request with object parameter (.NET WCF service)

Tags: c#, object, post, web, service

So, there's my question.

I am currently working on a WCF REST Service, and I need now to implement a method that allows me to create an account (user account). Searching on the Web didn't help me this time, that's why I'm asking someone who really know what I mean x).

So, this is my method :

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "users/{username}", 
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    [OperationContract]
    void PutUserAccount(string username, User u)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Entering method [PutUserAccount]");
        // Check if user exists
        User user = DBManager.FindUser(username);
        if (user == null)
        {
            try
            {
                //Create or update new user
                u.Id = GetUserLink(username);
                u.Notes = GetUserNotesLink(username);
                u.BlackListed = false;
                DBManager.AddUser(u);

                // Set status to created and include new URI in Location 
                //header
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.SetStatusAsCreated(GetUserProfile(username).Id);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("_PutUserAccount || Exception [" + e.Message + "]");
            }
        }
        else if (!DBManager.IsUserAuthorized(username, WebOperationContext.Current))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("_PutUserAccount - 1. This user isn't allowed to add users");
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            return;
        }
    }
```

And this is my "User" class :

```
[DataContract]
class _User
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool BlackListed { get; set; }
}
```

And the problem is: I can't do any request to fill "User u" it always returns these exceptions :

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in 
System.ServiceModel.Web.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in 
System.ServiceModel.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in 
System.ServiceModel.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in 
System.ServiceModel.dll
```

There is my POSTMAN request: 
PUT REQUEST: http://172.20.131.13/TDT/users/{RandomUser}
And my XML body:

```
<User>
    <Id>something</Id>
    <Username>RandomUser</Username>
    <Password>1234</Password>
    <Name>Random User</Name>
    <Email>random.user@randomemail.com</Email>
    <Notes>http://www.random-link.com</Notes>
    <BlackListed>false</BlackListed>
</User>
```

My question is, how do I have to build the request to pass a User to my Service ?

P.S. : I am using postman to test my code.

Comment: Where is the exception thrown? What are `GetUserLink` and `GetUserNotesLink` returning? You are using `User` in your controller, but you showed a `_User` class.
How does your Postman request and request-body look like?

Comment: @nilsK Hi, thank you for your reply. The exception is thrown before the request enters the method. I created a temporary class "Notes" as string because it's normally a URL (I thought it might be the problem, but it's not). (See edit for the postman request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, with a lot of struggle I managed to do it. All I had to do is to add the namespace of my object in the "User xmlns", and put the data in the correct order. This is my working request:

```
<User xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/namespace.lib.Objects" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <BlackListed>false</BlackListed>
    <Email>okabe.rintarou@achannel.com</Email>
    <Id></Id>
    <Name>Okabe Rintarou</Name>
    <Notes></Notes>
    <Password>1234</Password>
    <Username>Kyouma</Username>
</User>
```

It's been 1 week i'm trying to do this, pretty dumb from me.

Thank you